# REST API Design - Use of 'standard' field names for common data?

Tags: api, rest

I am creating my first REST API and have a question about naming conventions.

Much of the data I am exposing via my API is very common data fields that are found in many systems, e.g. first name, last name, addresses ect.

I'm assuming it makes sense not to use the same names on these fields that the database representation happens to use, but can I go one step further and follow some wider 'naming convention' for bits of data like that?

e.g. first name, middle name, surname, address line 1, address line 2, address line 3, postcode

Are there particular accepting 'naming conventions' for common data such at this?

Comment: you could have a look at the SCIM User schema https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7643#section-4.1 to see if it's of use. SCIM examples http://www.simplecloud.info/

Comment: See also the work at https://schema.org/docs/schemas.html

Comment: In a truly REST environment you try to keep the data as generic as possible and not introduce a tailor-made message structure. This allows you (or more particular the service) to convert the data to a wide range of formats if needed. Usually clients state their preferences using the `Accept` HTTP header. As such, user data like address and so on can be represented in multiple formats. One of these is i.e. [vCard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard) which has related media type definitions for xml, json and others.